# csv.DictReader error "_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte"

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using the following code to count the number of lines in a csv file

```
with open("filepath.csv",newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvtweet:
                    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvtweet)
                    num_coach_tweet = sum(1 for row in reader2)
```

and I get the following error:

```
line 112, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

I checked StackOverflow questions, and couldn't find one answer for the DictReader case.

Comment: Can you show your csv file?

Comment: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ef75f24132d4d7f285692f513d3817c4/17c.csv
This one.. But, is there a general solution that I can implement in my code? I don't want to change the data for thousands of similar .csv files :(

Comment: `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't help

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3a3a18d1c425ee76677d6983f9b7e9a9/5c.csv
Can you check this one? This one still gives me the same mistake.

Comment: That one gives me that error you are getting

Comment: Yeah I couldn't fix the problem in the second link.

Comment: Using `csv.reader(csvtweet)` seems to be working for both, still testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the second file you posted, there is a string of five null bytes near the end of the file.  I worked around it by pre-loading the file into memory, replacing all null bytes, then feeding it to `csv.DictReader` by wrapping the data in a `StringIO` that returns a file-like object:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

with open('5c.csv',newline='',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.replace('\x00','?')
    r = csv.DictReader(StringIO(data))
    for line in r:
        print(line)
```

In the 4th-to-last line there is a tweet containing:

```
At the 14 Fund Golf Classic. Played w/P.Berglund. Good man. Neat ?????moment: Dave Checketts...
```

The five question marks were the null bytes.  It seems that the 'csv' module explicitly disallows null bytes.  I also tried `data.replace('\x00','\x01')` and it was fine with it.

Comment: Thank you! That's an awesome tip. This code right now doesn't update the file right?